# Retrieve StackOverflow users with a gold badge in a specific Tag and Location

Tags: sql

I'm trying to write a query on the StackOverflow database to retrieve the users that have a gold badge on a specific Tag and Location.

Here's the thing I've done so far, but it retrieves the users that have any gold badge as well as the tag name I write in the field without considering whether this tag had a gold badge or not. For example, I write "python" as the tag name and "Iran" as the location, it retrieves the users have any gold badge but not a gold badge for the python tag.

```
SELECT DISTINCT u.Id AS [User Link], u.Location
FROM Users u
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT p.OwnerUserId, p.Id AS PostId, t.TagName
  FROM Posts p
  INNER JOIN PostTags pt ON p.Id = pt.PostId
  INNER JOIN Tags t ON pt.TagId = t.Id
  INNER JOIN Badges b ON p.OwnerUserId = b.UserId
  WHERE t.TagName LIKE '%' + ##TagName:string## + '%'
  AND b.Class = 1
) p ON u.Id = p.OwnerUserId
WHERE LOWER(u.Location) LIKE LOWER('%' + ##CountryName:string## + '%')
```

[Data.StackExchange link](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1708695/retrieve-stackoverflow-users-with-gold-badge-in-a-specific-tag-and-location)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT a.displayname, b.* 
FROM users A
INNER JOIN badges B
  on A.id = B.UserId
 where Location LIKE '%' + ##CountryName:string## + '%'
   AND B.class = 3
   and tagbased =1
   AND b.name like '%' + ##TagName:string## + '%'
 ORDER BY b.name, B.class ASC, B.Date ASC
```